# Backup banco de dados sql server express usando .bat

Tags: sql-server, backup

Fiz a criação de um arquivo `.bat` com o conteúdo:

```
USE T4FAT;  
GO  
BACKUP DATABASE T4FAT  
TO DISK = 'C:\Dropbox\MF-YCORN\BK_MF\T4FAT.Bak'  
   WITH FORMAT,  
      MEDIANAME = 'T4FATBackups',  
      NAME = 'Full Backup of T4FAT';  
GO
```

Adicionei no gerenciado de tarefas do *Windows server 2012*, ao testar o arquivo é chamado mais não está fazendo o *backup*, dentro do *sql server* funciona.

https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/kb/2019698

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para gera um backup usando o sql server express, é possível usando o script :

```
USE T4FAT;  
GO  
BACKUP DATABASE T4FAT  
TO DISK = 'C:\Dropbox\MF-YCORN\BK_MF\T4FAT.Bak'  
   WITH FORMAT,  
      MEDIANAME = 'T4FATBackups',  
      NAME = 'Full Backup of T4FAT';  
GO
```

ou usando um script que faz um backup de todos os bancos da instância:

Exemplo:

Criar um arquivo : backupsqlserver.sql

Com o conteúdo:

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(150) -- Nome do Database  
DECLARE @path VARCHAR(256) -- Caminho do arquivo de backup
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(256) -- Arquivo do backup  
DECLARE @dia VARCHAR(10) -- dia do backup
SET @dia = CONVERT (varchar,GETDATE(), 112) --formata o dia no padrao iso (yymmdd)

-- Define caminho de destino do backup
SET @path = 'C:\Dropbox\MF-YCORN\BK_MFCONSULTIN1\'  

-- Cria um cursor para selecionar todas as databases,  
--  excluindo model, msdb e tempdb
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
   SELECT name 
     FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases 
    WHERE name NOT IN ('model','msdb','tempdb')  

-- Abre o cursor e faz a primeira leitura 
OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name   

-- Loop de leitura das databases selecionadas
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN    
   SET @fileName = LTRIM( @path + @name + @dia + '.bak')  --remove os espacos 
   -- Executa o backup para o database
   BACKUP DATABASE @name TO DISK = @fileName WITH FORMAT;  

   FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name   
END   

-- Libera recursos alocados pelo cursor
CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Criar o arquivo : BACKUP.BAT

Com o conteúdo:

osql -U sa -P senha  -S servidor\SQLEXPRESS -i "C:\backupsqlserver.sql"

Comment: Usei o script para backup, porém observei que fazendo o backup de um banco manualmente o arquivo.bak ficou 1.4 Gb, o mesmo backup feito pelo script ficou 29 Mb. 
Alguém pode me explicar ?

Answer (score 0):

Faço o backup de vários clientes que tem o SQL Server.

> Quando coloca uma tarefa que chama um *arquivo.bat* pelo agendador de
>   tarefas para ser executada, ela parte do diretório System32 como
>   padrão, por isso pode-se resolver esse problema mudando o diretório
>   para chegar no diretório que está o executável que fará o backup pelo
>   comando `CD` Exemplo: `CD "MEU DIRETÓRIO"` ou apenas colocando os
>   executáveis necessários na pasta System32, particularmente é o que eu
>   faço pois independente de onde o bat estiver ele vai funcionar porque
>   os executáveis chamados nele serão reconhecidos pelo Windows.
>
> Utilizo o executável próprio SQL (sqlcmd.exe), o 7-zip (7za.exe) para
>   compactar e o forfiles.exe do Windows para apagar os backups antigos,
>   segue o batch que fiz:

```
@echo off
title "Titulo da Janela"
color b

SET date=
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /T') do set date=%%c%%b%%a

SET time=
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=: " %%a in ('time /T') do set time=%%c%%a%%b

REM **Variavel que vai guardar a data e hora no backup.
SET DATAATUAL=_%date%-%time%

REM **Nome do Backup para identificar caso faça backups de vários bancos.
SET NOMEBACKUP=Nome

REM **nome ou ip do computador que está com o banco de dados.
SET SQLHOST=localhost


SET SQLDATABASE=nomeDoBancoDeDados

REM **Usuário da base de dados
SET SQLUSER=user

REM **Senha da base de dados
SET SQLPASSWORD=pass

REM **Diretório de destino do arquivo de Backup 
SET DESTBACKUP=C:\


@echo Efetuando o backup do banco de dados, aguarde...
sqlcmd -U %SQLUSER% -P %SQLPASSWORD% -S %SQLHOST% -d %SQLDATABASE% -Q "backup database %SQLDATABASE% to disk='%DESTBACKUP%%NOMEBACKUP%%SQLDATABASE%%DATAATUAL%.bak'" > %DESTBACKUP%%NOMEBACKUP%%SQLDATABASE%%DATAATUAL%.log

7za a "%DESTBACKUP%%NOMEBACKUP%%SQLDATABASE%%DATAATUAL%.7z" "%DESTBACKUP%%NOMEBACKUP%%SQLDATABASE%%DATAATUAL%.bak"

if exist  "%DESTBACKUP%%NOMEBACKUP%%SQLDATABASE%%DATAATUAL%.bak"  del  /q "%DESTBACKUP%%NOMEBACKUP%%SQLDATABASE%%DATAATUAL%.bak"

REM *Apaga backups mais antigos que 31 dias, se quiser alterar é só mudar a quantidade de dias.
forfiles -p %DESTBACKUP% -s -d -31 -m *.7z -c "cmd /c del /f /q "@path" "

timeout /t 5
```